# Unable to view 15 MB Json data which I stored as JSONB data type in pgadmin4 version 7.1

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I am using timescale db to store timeseries data and json data. Why I unable to view 15 MB json data in table column which is JSONB datatype in pgadmin tool ? I am usning timescale db to store timeseries data and json data. but i could see 2 MB json data.

I have tried to store data in different datatypes like bytea. But still dont see the values of the data. I could see the data for 2 MB json data.

Comment: Use a different tool, pgAdmin might have it's limitations, like every tool has some.

Comment: Why would you make a huge JSON in the first place

Comment: @FrankHeikens  what are  the other tools we can use to login to timescale DB ?

Comment: Check the wiki for a list of clients: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients

Comment: Try open-source Dbeaver tool, this is best IDE for all databases (supports relations and non-relations DB's too) - https://dbeaver.io/